# How to extract a part of HBITMAP without using BitBlt

Tags: c++, windows, bitmap, gdi, hbitmap

I have a HBITMAP object. Without using BitBlt I would like to divide it into parts and obtain either the bits or new bitmaps of these parts

I can do it with BitBlt, but it is slow. It takes ~50 ms for extracting the part.
I have considered extracting regions of the byte array obtained from the bitmap, but this seems difficult. Is there any other way?

Thanks!

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/35763157/4603670

Comment: @BarmakShemirani : Thank you for sharing the link! How exactly can I extend that to copy a region? If the `HBITMAP` is 1920X1080, I'd like to take 500X500 sections from the byte array using memcpy. I'm still not able to understand the arrangement of the pixels. Any link elaborating that? Thanks!

Comment: I posted link to my own post, where I explain how to access the bits directly. Anyway, `BitBlt` is faster and more reliable, and it doesn't take 50 ms for doing that. Show what you have done already so we can see where it goes wrong...

Comment: @BarmakShemirani : Please find the code for `BitBlt` [here](http://pastebin.com/XX7xnwDy)
I am capturing parts of the screen (something like a grid) using threads. Each of this takes between 50-100 ms
I have also tried getting an existing `HBITMAP`, creating a `DC` for it and using `BitBlt` to capture parts of it (rather than capturing from `hDesktopDC`) but it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

`BitBlt` is very fast. If you are copying from another dc it takes a little too long. There is no way to get around that.

To word directly with pixels you need `GetDIBits(HDC hdc, HBITMAP hbitmap...)` but you still need `BitBlt` in order to setup the `hbitmap`

You can create a second memory dc, copy from first memory dc to second memory dc, this will be much faster. Using memory device context is like accessing bits directly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

long long milliseconds()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER fq, t;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&fq);
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&t);
    return 1000 * t.QuadPart / fq.QuadPart;
}

int main()
{
    HWND hwnd = GetDesktopWindow();
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
    HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    RECT rc;
    GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rc);
    int width = rc.right - rc.left;
    int height = rc.bottom - rc.top;

    int xPos = 100;
    int yPos = 100;
    int cropWidth = 500;
    int cropHeight = 500;

    HBITMAP hbitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, width, height);
    SelectObject(memdc, hbitmap);

    long long start;

    start = milliseconds();
    BitBlt(memdc, 0, 0, cropWidth, cropHeight, hdc, xPos, yPos, SRCCOPY);
    //this will take about 50 ms, or much less
    cout << milliseconds() - start << "\n"; 

    {
        //create a second memory dc:
        start = milliseconds();
        HDC memdc2 = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        HBITMAP hbitmap2 = CreateCompatibleBitmap(memdc2, 500, 500);
        SelectObject(memdc2, hbitmap2);
        BitBlt(memdc2, 0, 0, 500, 500, memdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

        //this will take about 1 ms:
        cout << "time: " << milliseconds() - start << "\n";
        DeleteObject(hbitmap2);
        DeleteDC(memdc2);
    }

    DeleteDC(memdc);
    DeleteObject(hbitmap);
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);

    return 0;
}
```

For the small you have shown it shouldn't be necessary to either access bits directly, or to use a second memory dc. You can copy any portion of the screen directly, it will only need 1 `BitBlt` operation.